# mysql show time slots avaliable and time slots busy from table

Tags: mysql, date, intervals

i have this table structure for bookings

```
|ID|timeBooked         | duration |
|2 |2013-05-09 11:10:00| 30       |
|1 |2013-05-09 14:40:00| 15       |
|AI| timespan          | int(4)   |
```

duration represent the duration in minutes.

so what i want is to return record set like this when i

query available time slots in 2013-05-09 between 00:00:00 and 23:00:00

```
|free_from|Free_until| Free |
|00:00:00 |11:10:00  | 1
|11:10:00 |11:40:00  | 0
|11:40:00 |14:40:00  | 1
|14:40:00 |14:55:00  | 0
|14:55:00 |23:00:00  | 1
```

is this possible by mysql alone ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, pure MySQL - as long as one likes those tricks. I need a Variable which is initialized to the "Begin" of the periods to show, something like now() normally.

First just the test data:

```
create table bookingEvents 
   (id int not null primary key auto_increment,
    timeBooked datetime, 
    duration int
   );


insert into bookingEvents values (null, '2013-05-13 13:22:00', 15);
insert into bookingEvents values (null, '2013-05-13 15:10:00', 45);
insert into bookingEvents values (null, '2013-05-13 19:55:00', 30);
insert into bookingEvents values (null, '2013-05-14 03:22:00', 15);
insert into bookingEvents values (null, '2013-05-14 08:19:00', 15);
```

Then initializing the "slider":

```
set @timeSlider='2013-05-10 00:00:00';
```

Then the select:

```
select if (d.name = 'Free', @timeSlider, b.timeBooked) as free_from,
       if (d.name = 'Free', b.timeBooked, @timeSlider := b.timeBooked + interval b.duration minute) as free_until,
       d.name as Free
from (select 1 as place, 'Free' as name union select 2 as place, 'Booked' as name) d 
inner join bookingEvents b 
having free_from < free_until
order by b.timeBooked, d.place;
```

Result:

```
+---------------------+---------------------+--------+
| free_from           | free_until          | Free   |
+---------------------+---------------------+--------+
| 2013-05-10 00:00:00 | 2013-05-13 13:22:00 | Free   |
| 2013-05-13 13:22:00 | 2013-05-13 13:37:00 | Booked |
| 2013-05-13 13:37:00 | 2013-05-13 15:10:00 | Free   |
| 2013-05-13 15:10:00 | 2013-05-13 15:55:00 | Booked |
| 2013-05-13 15:55:00 | 2013-05-13 19:55:00 | Free   |
| 2013-05-13 19:55:00 | 2013-05-13 20:25:00 | Booked |
| 2013-05-13 20:25:00 | 2013-05-14 03:22:00 | Free   |
| 2013-05-14 03:22:00 | 2013-05-14 03:37:00 | Booked |
| 2013-05-14 03:37:00 | 2013-05-14 08:19:00 | Free   |
| 2013-05-14 08:19:00 | 2013-05-14 08:34:00 | Booked |
+---------------------+---------------------+--------+
```

If you have a given End-Timestamp, then you have to pre-set that as @timeMaximum

```
set @timeSlider='2013-05-10 00:00:00';
set @timeMaximum='2013-05-14 08:35:00';


select if (d.name = 'Free', @timeSlider, b.timeBooked) as free_from,
       if (d.name = 'Free', b.timeBooked, @timeSlider := b.timeBooked + interval b.duration minute) as free_until,
       d.name as Free
from (select 1 as place, 'Free' as name union select 2 as place, 'Booked' as name ) as d 
inner join bookingEvents b 
having free_from < free_until
union select @timeSlider as free_from, @timeMaximum as free_until, 'Free' as Free
from (select 1) as d
where @timeSlider < @timeMaximum

order by free_from, free_until
;
```

Comment: nice :) i like it and execution time is 0.003 so not that bad :).. thanks

Answer (score 1):

not sure really how to get the free time records set, however I believe this is the right approach:

```
SELECT id, 
    DATE_FORMAT(timeBooked, '%H:%i:%s') AS initial_time, 
    DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(timeBooked, INTERVAL duration MINUTE), '%H:%i:%s') AS final_time, 
    duration
FROM your_table t1
WHERE DATE(timeBooked) = '2013-05-09'
ORDER BY t1.timeBooked ASC;
```

I hope it comes in handy!

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:
Obsoleted by my other answer. As long as you go simply through the ordered data the performance should be good.

Old:

I think in SQL alone the solution will get really slow as soon as a reasonable number of rows is in the table.

The SQL-table per se does not avoid overlappings.

I would use a table like that:

```
CREATE TABLE bookingEvents (id int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    event ENUM('start', 'end') NOT NULL,
    bookingId INT(11) NOT NULL,
    eventTime DATETIME NOT NULL,
    index (eventTime)
);
```

where bookingId references an additional table with informations about the booking.

Then you can list like that:

```
SELECT event, eventTime 
FROM bookingEvents 
WHERE (date or something)
ORDER BY eventTime;
```

you get (as long as the bookings don't overlap) alternating bookingStart and bookingEnd- times, which fill up like

```
time1  time2  booked
time2  time3  free
time3  time4  booked
time4  time5  free
```

you can at every entry easily check that free and booked match using the start/end check.

Insertion of a booking is as easy as

```
INSERT INTO bookingEvents (event, bookingId, eventTime) 
VALUES ('start', $bookingId, $timeBooked                          ), 
       ('end'  , $bookingId, $timeBooked + interval $length minute)
;
```

Answer (score 0):

@flaschenpost
Kindly Check your answer with two dates. I think it is not working as expected.
I am saying about this answer of yours
set @timeSlider='2013-05-10 00:00:00';
set @timeMaximum='2013-05-14 08:35:00';

select if (d.name = 'Free', @timeSlider, b.timeBooked) as free_from,
if (d.name = 'Free', b.timeBooked, @timeSlider := b.timeBooked + interval b.duration minute) as free_until,
d.name as Free
from (select 1 as place, 'Free' as name union select 2 as place, 'Booked' as name ) as d
inner join bookingEvents b
having free_from < free_until
union select @timeSlider as free_from, @timeMaximum as free_until, 'Free' as Free
from (select 1) as d
where @timeSlider < @timeMaximum

order by free_from, free_until;

not working. Always giving the constant answer

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35808793)