# MySQL INNER JOIN and SELECT

Tags: mysql

I am working on a small calendar application and practicing MySQL queries for finding available time slots based on the answer provided by flaschenpost

> [mysql show time slots avaliable and time slots busy from table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16459756/mysql-show-time-slots-avaliable-and-time-slots-busy-from-table)

I am studying the query step by step. I ran the query below separately to see what it returns exactly.

```
(select 1 as place, 'Free' as name union select 2 as place, 'Booked' as name ) as d 
inner join bookingEvents b
```

However, I got a syntax error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;

I also tried the query below but still getting the same error.

```
   select (select 1 as place, 'Free' as name union select 2 as place, 'Booked' as name ) as d
```

Please help.

Comment: please add  a  proper data sample and the expected  result   ... in you code there sintax  and strcutural error  ..and is not easy understand your goal

Comment: He has mentioned it from a different question which has such details.

Comment: Your syntax is wrong.  Follow the proper syntax.  `SELECT ... FROM ... JOIN... WHERE...`

Answer (score 3):

Those are tables that belong in the `from` portion of your query.

Do this:

```
select 
    *
from
    (select 1 as place, 'Free' as name union select 2 as place, 'Booked' as name ) as d 
    inner join bookingEvents b
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a `from` in the 2nd subquery so you are executing a select statement in none of the table.

On the 2nd query you have mentioned just put `* from` as

```
select * from (select 1 as place, 'Free' as name union select 2 as place,'Booked' as name ) as d
```